# Common SDK for Ubuntu Touch an "Classic"?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I started to develop Apps for Ubuntu using "quickly".
Nice toolset and I love python as Programming language.

I have a question regarding development for Mobile Devices and the "Classic" x86 Systems:
Will there be a common tool for all of them in the future?
Maybe PyQT and QML or something like that.

Can those future apps run on all flavours then?

Thanx in advanve for your time!

Greetings
andi

Answer (score 0):

I happen to love Python as well :)

The application development story on Ubuntu is essentially now based on the [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), which enables developers to write apps that can seamlessly run across devices and form factors.

While we still have Quickly content on [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com), we are in the process of shuffling content around to make the app developer site to focus solely on the Ubuntu SDK.

Comment: Hi David! Thanx a lot for your answer and explanation! Looking foreward to use the new SDK.